# how to store user-typed value before in to javascript variable before submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript

How to capture user input in textbox before form is submitted?

Each time my python app gets another recipient id for an email-send function, any text in the subject-line and message-body, that is typed in before submit is pressed, is erased by the page refresh.

So I want to capture subject-line and message-body before user hits "submit" button.

The (1) get-recipients and (2) enter subject-line and message-body are on the same page. If user types something into subject-line/message-body BEFORE choosing any message recipients, the subject-line and message-body are erased with page refresh when recipients are added.

Am a total JS beginner. I tried this, which helps serve to explain what's needed.

```
<input type="textbox" id="hello-world3" value="javascriptvar" onkeydown="var javascriptvar = document.getElementById('hello-world3').value;" />
```

Using above example, whatever I type gets replaced with the string "javascriptvar" during refresh.  How can I make what user types survive refresh before submit is pressed?

thanks,

Alex Glaros

Comment: Look into the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). JavaScript variables do not persist between page loads and the `value` attribute does not read JS variables.

Comment: I would say this is more related to how python Web Development  works than javascript. Web Development is stateless so if adding a recipient causes a postback  to the server you need to include the message and subject text in that post and repopulate the textboxes again. Or you would make the adding of recipient use Ajax so that the entire page is not refreshed. I have no knowledge of Web Development in python but I think this should give you some hint to your problem. I suppose python Web Development should include some mechanism for managing  state over postback.

Answer (score 0):

combining javascript and HTML is not recommended as it kills the readability

you can do add the value of the input in a [browser storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and then read that value from that storage. Note that this value stays storage so better remove it before submitting your form

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="your action url">
Name:  <input type="text" id="nameId" onchange="storeName()"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>
 //getting the  valule from the storage 
 var nameFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("storedName");
//checking the value is not empty
if(nameFromStorage!=undefined&&nameFromStorage!=null&&nameFromStorage.trim().length!=0&& typeof nameFromStorage == "string"){
    document.getElementById("nameId").value=nameFromStorage;
}
//storing the value in the storage
function storeName(){
var nameInputVal = document.getElementById("nameId").value;
localStorage.setItem("storedName",nameInputVal);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you are welcome and if the answer is correct, then your are supposed to specify that answer as correct by clicking the correct answer image left to the answer.

Comment: one more question:  to clear browser storage, is this the right command?

localStorage.removeItem("nameFromStorage");

Comment: yes it is, and the statement will only remove the item you have specified in the argument. Another important point to note is that **browser storage can store upto 5mb of data only**, so use it wisely.